# show horizontal browser scrollbar at some browser width

Tags: html, css

I have some content of min width 1200px on the screen. I resize it dynamically but below 1200px that content makes no sense, so I would like to have a horizontal browser scroll bar if the width of the browser window is less then 1200px. How can I achieve this? My first thought was using min-width, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
<div id="main-wrapper"></div>

<style>
#main-wrapper{
    min-width:1200px;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add overflow-x:auto:

```
#main-wrapper {
min-width:1200px;
overflow-x:auto;
```

}

https://jsfiddle.net/nectrf6w/

Comment: The question asked how to ensure an element would display if the screen had a width of 1200 pixels or less, not to ensure that the element itself displayed at a width of 1200 pixels.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for does look like [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

So you would have to do something like

```
@media(max-width: 1200px){
    #main-wrapper {
        //do something
    }
}
```